# "Express of a research interest" or "Expression of a research interest"

Tags: grammar, expression-choice

How to name a presentation slide with the list of research topics I am interested in?

It is not a research proposal, since there is no proposal.

I like `"Express of a research interest"`, is it grammatically correct and does it reflects the desired meaning?

Also, should it be `"Express"` or `"Expression"`?

Comment: Welcome to English. Your question might be more suited for our sister site [ell.se], make sure to read-up in their help centre how best to ask a question before you post. Expression is the noun you seek here.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I would chose this as the answer if you submit it. Thank you

Comment: It should  be _expression. Express_ in this context is a verb.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about naming something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid [**tautology**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tautology). Express your ideas without using the label ‘Express’ or ‘Expression’.

This is a classic editing issue, because it is easier to spot the problem with a second pair of eyes. You can easily express your idea without titling it ‘express’ or ‘expression’.

“Research Topics of Interest" works fine. Saying *of interest* is itself your expression of how appealing those topics are to you.

Sometimes the template itself introduces the problem by inviting you to insert *Expression of a research interest*. But you wouldn’t include the word *slide* within the very title of a presentation slide, like “Slide of Proposed Topics.“

There are exceptions to the rule of not labeling material with ‘label,’ such as Statement Of Work (SOW). In that case, the fixed title has the legal weight of “These are the terms we agreed on, as documented and signed in the Statement Of Work.”

As an aside, if you number your research titles in the body of the slide, it makes it easy for your audience to give you feedback like “Topic 3 is too generic.“ Or “Topic 2 and 5 will be the easiest for you to get grants.“